# Mac localhost:8080 doesn't work

Tags: macos, google-chrome, webpack

I'm working on macOS 10.13.3 and when I run my webpack project on default port 8080, I've got in chrome (any other browser, firefox or safari doesn't work too):

> This page isn’t working

on localhost:8080, but application works fine on 127.0.0.1:8080. When I change port in webpack.config for any other port i.e. 8081, it works fine, both on localhost:8081 and 127.0.0.1:8081.

My /private/etc/hosts file:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost

::1             localhost
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Do you get an error in the browser (from the server) or does it timeout? Check the browser's developer tools to find out.

Comment: I'm getting browser error "This page isn’t working. localhost didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" immediately. Chrome console is clear.

Comment: UPDATE: Eset's "Web access protection" was blocking ports 80, 8080 and 3128. Removing port 8080 resolve problem.